How to shade the intersection of three spaces in tikz?
Within this figure

I would like to shade only the space in which the three figures intersect. the code i've used is
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
        \draw[very thick,rotate=30] (3,2) .. controls (-1,.5) and (-1,-.5) .. (3,-2);
        \draw[clip][very thick] (1,-2) .. controls (0.5, 3) and (2.5,3) .. (3,-2);
        \draw[clip](-.5,0)  circle (2cm);
        \filldraw (-.5,0) circle (.1cm) node[left] {$w$};
        \draw[ultra thick] (-.5,0)  circle (2cm) ;
        \fill[gray!25,rotate=30] (3,2) .. controls (-1,.5) and (-1,-.5) .. (3,-2);
        \draw[ultra thick,rotate=30] (3,2) .. controls (-1,.5) and (-1,-.5) .. (3,-2);
        \draw[ultra thick] (1,-2) .. controls (0.5, 3) and (2.5,3) .. (3,-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

We can use insert path to define the circle, parabola and curve. Then use these paths to trace and clip them. The clip first!
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=.9,
    Circle/.style={
        ultra thick,
        insert path={(0,0) circle[radius=2]}
        },
    Parabola/.style={
        rotate=-60,
        insert path={(-2,3) parabola bend (0,0) ++(4,0)}
        },
    Curve/.style={
        insert path={(1,-2) .. controls (0.5, 3) and (2.5,3) .. (3,-2)}
        },
    ]
\begin{scope}
    \clip[Parabola];
    \clip[Curve];
    \fill[gray!50, Circle];
\end{scope}
%
\draw[Circle];
\draw[very thick,Parabola];
\draw[ultra thick,Curve];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks a lot. It runs perfectly!
